# What goes in the box?

Tags: pattern

This is a riddle I encountered recently and I can't solve it.

What goes in place of the question mark? No other info is given.

[image]

**EDIT:** Apparently there are a lot of possible answers, so I'll give some extra info on the context in which I found this riddle.
I found it in a schoolbook for children of about 10 to 12 years old. It's a Flemish textbook, so all word related answers should be with Dutch words.
However, since this riddle was in a chapter about patterns and lists, I'm inclined to go with Radhato's answer.

Comment: Questions such as this are typically closed for being too broad, as the number of possible answers/explanations is very high. If you have any more information (What context was this riddle given in? Is this part of a set of similar puzzles?)  that could help narrow the options, I would recommend adding it.

Answer (score 3):

Given we have no information there could be a lot of possible answers..
One I've come up with is (the one that seems the most plausible to me)

> J

Because

> The letters 'a' and 'c' have one between them (b), the letters 'c' and 'f' have two between them (d, e), therefor the next letter would be J (F..g..h..i..J) to continute the pattern with three letters in between.
>  'J' to 'O' (k l m n = 4)
>  'O' to 'U' (p q r s t = 5)

Another possible answer would be

> R

Because

> U - F - O and C - A - R (both vehicles?)

Comment: UFO is not a vehicle. It stands for "Unidentified flying OBJECT". everything that flies and you cannot identify is an UFO until you identify it.

Comment: I see @marius, was just another random idea that came to my mind while looking at the picture

Answer (score 3):

One of the many possiblities:

> **B**

As

> Considering the sum of characters in each row remain constant
>  **C**+**F**+**O** = 3+6+15 = 24
>  **U**+**A**+**B** = 21+1+2 = 24

Answer (score 1):

It could also be

> any of: A, B, D, F, K, L, N, O, P, R, U, W

Using the logic that

> There is a missing third row where all letters are equal and reading columns top-to-bottom form words:
>  CUT, FAT, O**A**T
>  CUE, FAE, O**B**E
>  CUD, FAD, O**D**D
>  CUT, FAT, O**F**T
>  CUE, FAE, O**K**E
>  CUD, FAD, O**L**D
>  CUE, FAE, O**N**E
>  CUP, FAP, O**O**P
>  CUE, FAE, O**P**E
>  CUB, FAB, O**R**B
>  CUT, FAT, O**U**T
>  CUN, FAN, O**W**N